# How to get scalogram in frequecy & time from continuous wavelet transform of time series

Tags: python, pywavelets

I have a time series for which I want to apply a continuous wavelet transform and plot the scalogram, where the scalogram is frequency on the y axis and time on the x axis.

I'm using *pywt's cwt* ([docs](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)), and the outputs are *numpy* arrays of the coefficients and the frequencies. I understand that the rows in the coefficients array correspond to the scales (widths) used in the transform, and the columns correspond to each time sample. I think, but am not certain, that the frequencies array corresponds to the peak frequency associated with the scale (so the frequencies array is the same size as the input scales array).

How can I plot a scalogram with frequency on the y axis and time on the x axis? I am not sure how to combine the coefficients and frequencies arrays, and I also don't know how to convert the x axis from number of x observations to time.

**Stand-Along Example Data & Libraries**

```
import numpy as np
import pywt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np. array([5.0000e-03, 2.5500e-01, 5.0500e-01, 7.5500e-01, 1.0050e+00,
       1.2550e+00, 1.5050e+00, 1.7550e+00, 2.0050e+00, 2.2550e+00,
       2.5050e+00, 2.7550e+00, 3.0050e+00, 3.2550e+00, 3.5050e+00,
       3.7550e+00, 4.0050e+00, 4.2550e+00, 4.5050e+00, 4.7550e+00,
       5.0050e+00, 5.2550e+00, 5.5050e+00, 5.7550e+00, 6.0050e+00,
       6.2550e+00, 6.5050e+00, 6.7550e+00, 7.0050e+00, 7.2550e+00,
       7.5050e+00, 7.7550e+00, 8.0050e+00, 8.2550e+00, 8.5050e+00,
       8.7550e+00, 9.0050e+00, 9.2550e+00, 9.5050e+00, 9.7550e+00,
       1.0005e+01, 1.0255e+01, 1.0505e+01, 1.0755e+01, 1.1005e+01,
       1.1255e+01, 1.1505e+01, 1.1755e+01, 1.2005e+01, 1.2255e+01,
       1.2505e+01, 1.2755e+01, 1.3005e+01, 1.3255e+01, 1.3505e+01,
       1.3755e+01, 1.4005e+01, 1.4255e+01, 1.4505e+01, 1.4755e+01,
       1.5005e+01, 1.5255e+01, 1.5505e+01, 1.5755e+01, 1.6005e+01,
       1.6255e+01, 1.6505e+01, 1.6755e+01, 1.7005e+01, 1.7255e+01,
       1.7505e+01, 1.7755e+01, 1.8005e+01, 1.8255e+01, 1.8505e+01,
       1.8755e+01, 1.9005e+01, 1.9255e+01, 1.9505e+01, 1.9755e+01,
       2.0005e+01, 2.0255e+01, 2.0505e+01, 2.0755e+01, 2.1005e+01,
       2.1255e+01, 2.1505e+01, 2.1755e+01, 2.2005e+01, 2.2255e+01,
       2.2505e+01, 2.2755e+01, 2.3005e+01, 2.3255e+01, 2.3505e+01,
       2.3755e+01, 2.4005e+01, 2.4255e+01, 2.4505e+01, 2.4755e+01,
       2.5005e+01, 2.5255e+01, 2.5505e+01, 2.5755e+01, 2.6005e+01,
       2.6255e+01, 2.6505e+01, 2.6755e+01, 2.7005e+01, 2.7255e+01,
       2.7505e+01, 2.7755e+01, 2.8005e+01, 2.8255e+01, 2.8505e+01,
       2.8755e+01, 2.9005e+01, 2.9255e+01, 2.9505e+01, 2.9755e+01,
       3.0005e+01, 3.0255e+01, 3.0505e+01, 3.0755e+01, 3.1005e+01,
       3.1255e+01, 3.1505e+01, 3.1755e+01, 3.2005e+01, 3.2255e+01,
       3.2505e+01, 3.2755e+01, 3.3005e+01, 3.3255e+01, 3.3505e+01,
       3.3755e+01, 3.4005e+01, 3.4255e+01, 3.4505e+01, 3.4755e+01,
       3.5005e+01, 3.5255e+01, 3.5505e+01, 3.5755e+01, 3.6005e+01,
       3.6255e+01, 3.6505e+01, 3.6755e+01, 3.7005e+01, 3.7255e+01,
       3.7505e+01, 3.7755e+01, 3.8005e+01, 3.8255e+01, 3.8505e+01,
       3.8755e+01, 3.9005e+01])

y = np.array([-2.90025342e-03, -6.40420148e-02, -5.14428368e-02, -5.24396156e-02,
       -2.36905934e-02, -7.33774047e-02,  6.96917443e-01,  1.10640628e+00,
        2.14842575e+00,  3.59673555e+00,  4.73432960e+00,  6.49741055e+00,
        7.29974071e+00,  1.01759353e+01,  1.02030717e+01,  1.36557766e+01,
        1.41826988e+01,  7.76774453e+00,  3.82632036e+00, -2.70456335e+00,
       -1.96618648e+01, -3.66985195e+01,  2.99333347e+01,  2.36009095e+01,
        1.10220943e+01, -2.95258984e+00,  6.80386136e+00, -2.70166763e+01,
       -3.76209305e+01, -1.35082003e+01,  4.60503863e+00, -9.60422448e+00,
       -1.43916205e+01, -1.26012282e+01, -2.13207866e+01, -3.26687352e+01,
       -2.41891688e+01, -2.97832448e+00, -2.80885014e+00,  7.05782776e+00,
        7.75577641e+00,  7.42433815e+00,  1.71676749e+00,  1.79335514e+00,
        3.37780022e+00,  9.75024672e+00,  1.03110319e+01,  1.42435904e+00,
        2.48130497e+00,  6.72502952e+00,  5.29311955e+00,  1.02966186e+01,
        1.28654499e+01,  1.27711678e+01,  7.34488122e+00,  4.24580786e+00,
        3.43792737e+00,  7.14184919e+00,  5.87025700e+00,  2.82831733e+00,
        1.41092267e+00, -2.62424149e+00, -6.35504810e+00, -4.29696255e+00,
       -5.27593166e+00, -6.70304826e+00, -7.73215169e+00, -1.06058497e+01,
       -1.11609626e+01, -5.82899263e+00, -3.14857074e+00, -1.82479856e+00,
        1.73553141e+00,  4.10008240e+00,  1.95158521e+00,  6.46081039e-02,
        6.19934053e-01,  3.59542159e+00,  7.38641899e+00,  8.35768231e+00,
        8.65572196e+00,  7.42586536e+00,  5.86887591e+00,  5.36210626e+00,
        3.56410283e+00, -2.27375587e-01, -2.05785024e+00, -2.41085077e+00,
       -2.47258719e+00, -1.92065302e+00, -2.33531757e+00, -3.78717114e+00,
       -5.43768739e+00, -6.22146733e+00, -6.32672517e+00, -8.74872401e+00,
       -9.63365954e+00, -8.04706703e+00, -3.42860196e+00, -2.38901992e-02,
        2.16031975e+00,  4.84801654e+00,  6.73393543e+00,  7.56246002e+00,
        5.51142721e+00,  3.96078924e+00,  1.00253884e+00, -2.56086766e+00,
       -3.32289364e+00, -7.95432505e-01,  8.01013095e-01,  2.44769438e+00,
        2.83964569e+00,  4.17925704e+00,  4.31245244e+00,  2.89684591e+00,
        1.03658591e+00, -8.09516543e-01, -4.15390067e+00, -5.43798992e+00,
       -7.62820752e+00, -7.27063191e+00, -5.52509620e+00, -3.71587359e+00,
       -1.26491743e+00, -1.49203623e+00, -9.37770362e-01,  1.55140704e+00,
        1.88526353e+00,  2.98912902e+00,  4.35663676e+00,  4.36104650e+00,
        3.58104564e+00,  3.55686396e+00,  1.47853154e+00,  2.06093445e-01,
        5.86736552e-01,  1.26966443e+00,  6.73485660e-01,  1.17591023e+00,
        1.96013272e+00,  1.18115362e+00, -4.55632643e-01, -2.13888010e+00,
       -2.23202762e+00, -2.03038079e+00, -1.05057577e+00, -3.30290779e-01,
       -4.42753086e-01, -1.94528619e-01,  2.85416068e-01,  1.88951595e-01,
        9.65445495e-02, -5.39501681e-02, -1.04898435e-01, -9.69066588e-02,
       -2.98158805e-02])
```

**Plot Time Series**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_title('time series')
ax.set_xlabel('time (sec)')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
```

[image]

**CWT & Failed Plotting Attempt, Help Needed Here**

```
scales = np.arange(35, 2186, 43)
timestep = x[1] - x[0]
coefs, freqs = pywt.cwt(y, scales, 'morl', timestep)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.imshow(coefs, aspect='auto',)
ax.set_title('scalogram')
ax.set_xlabel('number of x observations, but I want this in time (sec)?')
ax.set_ylabel('coefficients for number of scales, \n but I want this in freq (Hz)?')
```

[image]

Comment: This belongs on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Ok, I will post over there, thank you, you can close the question if you need